# Is it possible to know if an entity is being removed because of a cascade operation?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a situation where I'd like to know if an entity is being removed manually, or as a result of a parent entity being removed (with `cascade = {"remove"}` being set on the parent.)

I have a pre-remove event listener that needs to react accordingly depending on the situation.

Is this possible?